# Excel 2007 3-color scale with negative values

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Given the following data

```
values
 12
 2
 0
-2
-12
```

I want to add a 3-color scale conditional formatting to the values column such that cells

```
< 0 are green
= 0 are white
> 0 are red
```

Using formulas like

```
=$A$1<0 for Minimum
=$A$1=0 for Midpoint
=$A$1>0 for Masximum
```

does not seem to work.  cell value > 0 is red, cell < 0 is green, but cell = 0 is NOT white (it is green)

What's the right way to define the formulas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select the cells and choose the color white, it will be default
- Put the rules for less than 0 and greater than 0 only

Comment: Tried this with a 2-color scale (I presumed that is what I needed since I was just using 2 values.  I used formulas =$a$1<0 and =$a$1>0 but the cell was colored red.

Comment: Got it, just used 2 standard rules for < 0 and > 0

Comment: Noel, it sounds like S.Mark's answer was correct, no? If so, you should give him the check mark, and probably an up-vote, too, yes? (I'm giving +1, in any case.)